# Rails - getting ID of currently created element with formobject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to know how can i get ID of currently created Model record, which was saved by Form Object. I have:

```
@object_form.save

id = @parent.objects.last.id
```

i would like to change it into something more meaningful like:\

```
@object_form.save

id = (currently saved OBJECT.id)
```

Comment: Try `@object_form.id`

Comment: `@object_form.reload.id`

Comment: I Already tried object_form.id, hope reload will work

Comment: undefined method `reload' for #<ObjectForm:0x007feb9c96b3d0> after using reload on @object_form

Comment: Are you sure that your object was saved? Try `@object_form.persisted?` what you get?

Comment: It should be saved and should return `@object_form.id` no problem really

Comment: Yeah im quite sure, It is an action after checking if object_form was created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're *saving* the object, and if that *save* is successful, you'll be able to just reference the `id` of the newly *saved* object:

```
id = @object_form.id if @object_form.save
```

You have to remember that you're *not* saving the "form", but an `ActiveRecord` object. Thus, if you've still got the `@instance_variable` available from the save, it will return the newly populated `id` method.